# Drove exactly a mile on water in the reservoir. Overheating after coolant added. What could be the problem?

Tags: cooling-system, coolant-reservoir

So I drove to the gas station to put air in my tire when I realized I forgot to clamp down a coolant hose going to radiator after working on swapping the alternator. My hood was steaming and there was coolant all over the ground and emptied the reservoir.. i would’ve bought coolant right there but I only had a dollar for air. I tightened the hose and put water into the reservoir. Drove a mile straight back home with no more leaks but is still over heating after I added coolant and water, 50/50. And also doesn’t blow out hot air with temp at the highest. Not much of a car person idk what it could be, trapped air? Could I have messed something up even worse? PLS HELP

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It very well could be air in the system or you could have done permanent damage to the engine by overheating it in the first place (without coolant in the system). Plain water would not have caused issues, unless you dumped it in when the engine was hot.

Comment: I bled the air in the cooling system by removing the radiator cap and filling it up to the rim. All is good, the heater works and doesn’t overheat. Preaciate it Paul